# A jQuery scrollTop(); with Transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, offset, scrolltop

I can't figure out of to make scroll, (when a div is clicked), and make it smooth. (like not going straight to the scroll position)

Here's my code:

```
$('.about-center').click(function() {
    var div = document.getElementById('ABOUT');
    var pos = div.offsetTop;
    
    $(window).scrollTop(pos);
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try this one:

```
$('.about-center').click(function() {
    var div = $('#ABOUT');
    var pos = div.offset().top;

    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:pos},2000); // will take two seconds to scroll to the element
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I know it's a simple question... I'll acceopt it!